# Add a class to div when there is an error on #div.load?(Jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I need to show my error message in **red** when the div.load errors out as shown in the code. If it is success, I would render the content as it is, How can I do this?

```
$('#TermsAndConditions').load(termsconditionsurl, null, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry there was an error: ";
    $(this).addClass("error");

            $("#TermsAndConditions").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);


    }
});
```

Thanks,
Adarsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the div has ID "TermsAndConditions" as per your selector, you would do this:

```
if (status == "error") 
{         
  var msg = "Sorry there was an error: ";     
  $(this).addClass("error")
}
```

And in css have:

```
.error
{
  color: red;
}
```

EDIT:

You should put this in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div = $("#TermsAndConditions");

  if (status == "error")
  {
   var msg = "sorry there was an error:";
   div.val(msg);
    div.addClass("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: I added that class(edited in my question) But I couldnt see the error message in red, Anything possible misses from my side? There is this .html rendering of the error message(updated in my question) which i missed earlier.

Comment: you are using the load command, which may be triggered before the HTML is rendered.  Try putting the code in $(document).ready(function() { .. }.

Comment: Also, in your code you are not assigning the message to the div.

Comment: Hmmm, this load is done on a button click event, so in this case, I dont think I can put this in $(document).ready or Can i?

Comment: you could put it inside a $(document).ready(function() { ("#MyButton").click(function() { ... put your code here ... }); }